# subversion - path not found on commit (tortoise)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I have a local folder which used to be named "XYZ".  It is now called "ABC".  When I try to commit files in this directory, I get a "Path not found" error telling me "XYZ" does not exist.  Sure enough, when I look in the repository browser, the "XYZ" directory is not there, but I'm wondering how I can tell tortoise to stop looking for "XYZ" and instead to treat it as "ABC".

P.S. - the "ABC" directory is appearing in the remote repository, so it just seems like even though the local name has changed, the remote path it points to has not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the folder "ABC" to the repository. When you next do a commit, SVN should completely remove folder "XYZ" and add everything that was in it as a new folder, "ABC".

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  The problem is that the ABC repository is already in the remote repository as an added directory, which is why this is so strange.  I have ABC both locally and remotely, and yet it's telling me it's trying to commit to XYZ.

Comment: Can you delete ABC locally and just obtain a new copy of it from the repository?

Answer (score 4):

This already has an answer but there was a much simpler way to fix this when I got the error.

**To reproduce:**

```
svn mv /dir/subdir newdir/subdir/
svn rm /newdir/subdir --force
svn ci
svn: E160016: Path '/newdir/subdir' not present
```

**To resolve:**

```
mkdir /newdir/subdir
svn add /newdir/subdir
svn ci
svn rm /newdir/subdir --force
svn ci
```

That worked for me, it required re-creating the missing dir, tricking SVN into thinking it was adding it instead of deleting it.  Then deleting it after an intermediate commit.  Its dirty but it poses less risk to losing the other changes.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my working copy after I broke it by killing svn in the middle of an operation.